# =AutoPairsDelete() is inserted when using kite and auto-pairs in vim

Tags: python, vim, vi, kite

I am currently using the vim editor.
I am facing a problem right now.
If I use [kite](https://kite.com/?utm_expid=.fUEDKRYBQ7u5RlYdVIj9MQ.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F) and [auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs/blob/master/plugin/auto-pairs.vim) together in vim, `=AutoPairsDelete()` will be inserted when I press the Back space key repeatedly.
I suspect it's due to `set completeopt=menuone,noinsert` in `~/.vimrc`, but removing this line makes kite unusable.
How can I solve this problem?
Below is an excerpt of my `~/.vimrc`.

```
" plug

silent! if plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
" Colors
Plug 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Plug 'tomasr/molokai'
Plug 'colepeters/spacemacs-theme.vim'
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'


Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
Plug 'derekwyatt/vim-protodef', { 'for': ['c', 'cpp', 'objc'] }
Plug 'derekwyatt/vim-fswitch', { 'for': ['c', 'cpp', 'objc'] }
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on': 'NERDTreeToggle' }


" Navigation
Plug 'majutsushi/tagbar', { 'on': 'TagbarToggle' }
Plug 'derekwyatt/vim-fswitch', { 'for': ['c', 'cpp', 'objc'] }
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on': 'NERDTreeToggle' }
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plug 'dyng/ctrlsf.vim'
Plug 'fholgado/minibufexpl.vim'
Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'

call plug#end()
endif

nnoremap <tab>   <c-w>w
nnoremap <S-tab> <c-w>W
nnoremap <Leader>hw <C-W>h
nnoremap <Leader>jw <C-W>j
nnoremap <Leader>kw <C-W>k
nnoremap <Leader>lw <C-W>l


" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" tarbar
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

inoremap <F2> <esc>:TagbarToggle<cr>
nnoremap <F2> :TagbarToggle<cr>

let tagbar_left=1
let tagbar_width=32
let g:tagbar_sort = 0
let g:tagbar_compact=1
let g:tagbar_type_cpp = {
 \ 'ctagstype' : 'c++',
 \ 'kinds'     : [
     \ 'c:classes:0:1',
     \ 'd:macros:0:1',
     \ 'e:enumerators:0:0', 
     \ 'f:functions:0:1',
     \ 'g:enumeration:0:1',
     \ 'l:local:0:1',
     \ 'm:members:0:1',
     \ 'n:namespaces:0:1',
     \ 'p:functions_prototypes:0:1',
     \ 's:structs:0:1',
     \ 't:typedefs:0:1',
     \ 'u:unions:0:1',
     \ 'v:global:0:1',
     \ 'x:external:0:1'
 \ ],
 \ 'sro'        : '::',
 \ 'kind2scope' : {
     \ 'g' : 'enum',
     \ 'n' : 'namespace',
     \ 'c' : 'class',
     \ 's' : 'struct',
     \ 'u' : 'union'
 \ },
 \ 'scope2kind' : {
     \ 'enum'      : 'g',
     \ 'namespace' : 'n',
     \ 'class'     : 'c',
     \ 'struct'    : 's',
     \ 'union'     : 'u'
 \ }
\ }

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" nerdtree
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

inoremap <F3> <esc>:NERDTreeToggle<CR>
nnoremap <F3> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>


let NERDTreeWinSize=22
let NERDTreeWinPos="right"
let NERDTreeShowHidden=0
let NERDTreeMinimalUI=1
let NERDTreeAutoDeleteBuffer=1


" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" YouCompleteMe
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

set completeopt-=preview

nnoremap <leader>jc :YcmCompleter GoToDeclaration<CR>
nnoremap <leader>jd :YcmCompleter GoToDefinition<CR>
inoremap <leader>; <C-x><C-o>

let g:ycm_complete_in_comments=1
let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf=0
let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_tags_files=0
let g:ycm_min_num_of_chars_for_completion=1
let g:ycm_cache_omnifunc=0
let g:ycm_seed_identifiers_with_syntax=1
" let g:ycm_filetype_whitelist = {'cpp':1}
let g:ycm_filetype_blacklist = {'python':1}
let g:ycm_filetype_specific_completion_to_disable = {'python':1}

" }}}
" set statusline=%<%f\ %h%m%r%{kite#statusline()}%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
" set laststatus=2  " always display the status line
set completeopt=menuone,noinsert
```

Comment: Consider asking questions about Vim on [vi.se], you might be able to reach more Vim experts there... (Though many of them hang out here as well.)

Comment: thanks for your comment ! I post same question on it!